# docker unit test setup

Tags: unit-testing, lua, docker, openresty

I want to setup a unit test environment for my product. I have a web application build on nginx in Lua which use mysql and redis. **I think docker will be good for this although i am new to docker**. My application runs on centos server (production server).

I am planning to setup different container for mysql,redis and webapp and then write UT application (unit test for Lua using Busted framework) in my mac (My development machine is MAC) or VM to test it. The UT application will talk to docker container nginx and nginx will use container mysql and redis. Is this good ? If yes ,can someone guide me how to do this? maybe some good link? If no , what could be better way. I have already tried using vagrant but that took too much time which shouldn't be in my UT case.

Comment: thanks for edit @NicolBolas

Comment: I am afraid you are mixing terminology here. Unit tests are tests designed to check a component in isolation. What you are trying to run are integration tests in which you check how everything works together.

Comment: @Akira i agree. Actually i am trying to setup environment for integration testing along with unit test setup (using busted framework). It will help me to test my app thoroughly.

Comment: I created this couple of months ago, may give you some ideas how to do this: https://github.com/boynux/docker-dust

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an example how we setup our project template you may have a look at [`phundament/app`](https://github.com/phundament/app) and its testing setup.

We are using a dockerized [GitLab](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab) installation with a [customized runner](https://github.com/schmunk42/docker-gitlab-runner), which is able to execute `docker-compose`.

> Note! The runner itself is running on a separate Docker host.

We are using `docker-compose.yml` to define the [services](https://github.com/phundament/app/blob/4.0.0-rc15/docker-compose.yml) in a stack with adjustments for [development](https://github.com/phundament/app/blob/4.0.0-rc15/docker-compose.override-dist.yml) and [testing](https://github.com/phundament/app/blob/4.0.0-rc15/build/compose/test.override.yml).

The [CI configuration](https://github.com/phundament/app/blob/4.0.0-rc15/.gitlab-ci.yml) is optimized to handle multiple concurrent tests of isolated stacks, this is just done by specifying a custom `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME`.

Some in-depth documentation about our testing process and useful information about `docker-compose` and dockerized CI.

- [#testing README](https://github.com/phundament/app/tree/4.0.0-rc15#testing)
- [#testing Docs](https://github.com/phundament/docs/blob/master/4-testing/testing.md)
- [CI builds](https://git.hrzg.de/phundament/app/builds?scope=all)
- [Extending services and Compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/)
- [Docker-in-Docker for CI?](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/)

*Finally, [Travis CI](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/docker/) also supports Docker since a while, but I haven't tested this approach at all.*

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to Docker based CI, please look at Drone:

- [Official page](https://drone.io/)
- [Github repo](https://github.com/drone/drone)
- [Tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-perform-continuous-integration-testing-with-drone-io-on-coreos-and-docker)

There some are drawbacks to this solution (like size of images), but it will get you off the grounds.